# LinkedIn framework still does not contain bitcode

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

In the latest version 1.0.6 it says it does, but doesn't:

```
$ otool -l linkedin-sdk | grep '__bitcode'
```

Produces no output.

Answer (score 2):

Until LinkedIn update their SDK, the only solution is to disable bitcode. Build settings > Enable Bitcode to no.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I was answering my own question, and this is the only solution for end users. I have added more detail.

Comment: The nasty thing is they officially state that the framework does contain bitcode. I'm wondering about the quality of their code if they haven't tested whether such a tiny setting is indeed enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn recently released v1.0.7 of their iOS SDK, which corrects an earlier issue in v1.0.6 with bitcode support.  Note that it is only available on the arm-64 architecture, so the correct command-line test would be

```
otool -arch arm64 -l linkedin-sdk | grep '__bitcode'
```

Comment: Bitcode is available for both armv7 and arm64 architectures (checked with otool). The problems are that is missing the armv7s architecture and Pods-dummy.o wasn't build with (full) bitcode (the Pods used by the library should be built with bitcode and default architectures armv7 armv7s arm64).