# Bitcode errors with LinkedIn SDK

Tags: ios, linker, xcode7, linkedin-api, bitcode

There are a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670210/linkedin-sdk-bitcode-ios-9) of [older](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572086/linkedin-framework-still-does-not-contain-bitcode) questions concerning Bitcode support in LinkedIn's SDK. They seem to concur with [LinkedIn's documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk#ios9) that version 1.0.7 of their SDK supports Bitcode.

However, when I attempt to archive our app (using Xcode 7.3.1, and including that SDK), I get this error during the linking stage:

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/…*redacted*…/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(Pods-dummy.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture arm64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Inspecting the framework (per an earlier question) seems to show Bitcode in both arm64 and armv7 slices:

```
otool -arch arm64 -l linkedin-sdk | grep '__bitcode'
otool -arch armv7 -l linkedin-sdk | grep '__bitcode'
```

Does anyone else see this result? Is there any way to fix it, **other** than turning off Bitcode support for the app?

On a tangentially related note, if I do turn off Bitcode, and get a successful build, I get about 10 of these warnings (that look to me like misconfiguration of their CI system):

> while processing /Users/…*redacted*…/linkedin-sdk.framework/linkedin-sdk(LISDKAccessToken.o):
>   warning: /export/home/tester/hudson/data/workspace/MP_TRUNKDEV_POSTCOMMIT/ios-sdk_3939eff14f36b69f3fa38c9db85f0b182a1fc733/build/linkedin-sdk/ModuleCache/22OID7V7UWIA2/Foundation-73OMMCO56G8Z.pcm: No such file or directory
>
> note: Module debugging should be disabled when shipping static libraries.

Comment: Hi, was this resolved? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: For all I can tell, LinkedIn doesn't have anyone working on the iOS SDK any more: they haven't released a new version of the library since 19 January 2016, they haven't posted about it on their blog since 11 September 2015, I haven't seen any evidence of anyone here on SO…

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way to fix would be if they rebuild the SDK with Bitcode support enabled correctly.
Without them enabling it correctly, the only other work around which, you already found out is disabling Bitcode support in your app.

I know you already tagged this question with 'linkedin' tag but, if they don't reply in time best is to contact them directly:
https://developer.linkedin.com/support

Hope that helps.

Kind regards,
Mukund

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't actually provide a way to contact that them directly for developer support any more. That page you linked to directs people here to SO, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using version 1.0.7 and I had the exactly same problem when I includes the Other Linker Flags `-ObjC` and bitcode set to `yes` together.

But, I'm able to archive  with bitcode set to `yes` without `-ObjC` flag.